# JPA Eclipselink One-to-one relationship child is persisted only sometimes, fails when persisting big batch

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I've had this problem for a while when I try to persist the parent, the child is only sometimes persisted. I'm using Eclipselink as my persistence provider.

I have two entities:

The parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mp_item")
public class Item extends BaseShopEntity {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ItemGroupSuggestion itemGroupSuggestion;
 // more code
}
```

The child:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mp_itemgroup_suggestion", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "item_id" }))
public class ItemGroupSuggestion extends BaseShopEntity {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Item item;
// more code
}
```

I have a batch job which adds a suggestion to about 1000 items at a time.

I create a suggestion like this, setting the references on both sides:

```
    public void setItemGroupSuggestion(ItemGroupSuggestion itemGroupSuggestion) {
    itemGroupSuggestion.setItem(this);
    this.itemGroupSuggestion = itemGroupSuggestion;
}
```

After creating the suggestions for these 1000 items, I then try to batch-save by calling the following method:

```
    public List<Item> saveAll(List<Item> items) {
    List<List<Item>> partitions = Lists.partition(items, 100);
    List<Item> savedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<Item> partitionedItems : partitions) {
        for (Item item : partitionedItems) {
            savedItems.add(save(item));
        }
        itemRepository.flush();
    }
    return savedItems;
}

    public Item save(Item item) {
    return this.itemRepository.save(item);
}
```

What I've observed: When the amount of items is small, less than one hundred, then it is more often possible to persist the children. However, when providing a list of a thousand items, it almost never works. No exception or anything interesting in the logs. A lot of insert statements are produced in the logs no matter if the persisting succeeds or not.

The logs are filled with a lot of these entries:

```
[EL Fine]: 2022-10-07 16:31:33.275--ClientSession(1703172514)--Connection(711048631)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-3,5,main])--SELECT @@IDENTITY
[EL Fine]: 2022-10-07 16:31:33.284--ClientSession(1703172514)--Connection(711048631)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-3,5,main])--INSERT INTO mp_suggested_item_group (itemgroup_id, suggestion_id) VALUES (?, ?)
[EL Fine]: 2022-10-07 16:31:33.284--ClientSession(1703172514)--Connection(711048631)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-3,5,main])-- bind => [1, 103197]
[EL Fine]: 2022-10-07 16:31:33.284--ClientSession(1703172514)--Connection(711048631)--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-3,5,main])-- bind => [43093, 103197]
```

I've tried adding cascading to the child-side, and partitioning the list (see the saveAll-method) to see if it has anything to do with the flush getting too many items to insert into the database.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a reason why this kept happening. It had to do with transaction-management. It was fixed by adding the annotation:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public List<Item> saveAll(List<Item> items) {
        List<List<Item>> partitions = Lists.partition(items, 100);
        List<Item> savedItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Item> partitionedItems : partitions) {
            for (Item item : partitionedItems) {
                savedItems.add(save(item));
            }
            itemRepository.flush();
        }
        return savedItems;
    }
```